# How to handle network connectivity loss in the middle of REST POST request?

Tags: rest, error-handling, network-programming

REST POST is used to create resources.

Let's say we have resource url
"http://example.com/cars"

We want to create a new car.
We POST to "**http://example.com/cars**" with JSON payload containing car properties (color, weight, model, etc).

**Server** receives the request, **creates a new car**, sends a response over the network.

At this point **network fails** (let's say router stops working properly and ignores every packet).

Client fails with TCP timeout (like 90 seconds).
Client has no idea **whether car was created or not**.
Also client haven't received car resource id, so it can't GET it to check if it was created.

**Now what?**
How do you handle this?
You can't simply retry creating, because retrying will just create a duplicate (which is bad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> REST POST is used to create resources.

[HTTP POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) is used for lots of things.  REST doesn't particularly care; it just wants resources that support a uniform interface, and hypermedia.

> At this point network fails

Bummer!

> Now what? How do you handle this? You can't simply retry creating, because retrying will just create a duplicate (which is bad).

This is a general messaging concern, not directly related to REST.  The most common solution is to use the [Idempotent Receiver](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/IdempotentReceiver.html) pattern.  In short, you
need to define your messages so that the receiver has enough information to recognize the request as something that has already been done.

Ideally, this is being supported at the [business level](https://www.infoq.com/articles/no-reliable-messaging).

Idempotent collections of values are often straight forward; we just need to be thinking *sets*, rather than *lists*.

Idempotent collections of entities are trickier; if the request includes an identifier for the new entity, or if we can compute one from the data provided, then we can think of our collection as a hash.

If none of those approaches fits, then there's another possibility.  Instead of performing an idempotent mutation of the collection, we make the mutation of the collection itself idempotent.  Think "compare and swap" - we encode into the request information that identifies the current state of the collection; is that state is still current when the request arrives, then the mutation is applied.  If the condition does not hold, then the request becomes a no-op.

Translating this into HTTP, we make a small modification to the protocol for updating the collection resource.  First, we GET the current representation; and in the meta data the server provides [validators](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2) that can be used in subsquent requests.  Having obtained the validator, the client evaluates the current representation of the resource to determine if it needs to be changed.  If the client decides to make a change, then submits the change with an [If-Match](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.1) or an [If-Unmodified-Since](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.4) header including the validator.  The server, before processing the requests, then considers the validator, immediately abandoning the request with [412 Precondition Failed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.2).

Thus, if a conditional state-changing request is lost, the client can at its own discretion repeat the request without concern that server will misunderstand the client's intent.

Answer (score 0):

Retry it a limited number of times, with increasing delays between the attempts, and make sure the transaction concerned is idempotent.

> because retrying will just create a duplicate (which is bad).

It is indeed, and it needs fixing, see above. It should be impossible in your system to create two entries with the same attributes. This is easily accomplished at the database level. You can attain idempotence by having the transaction return the same thing whether the entry already existed or was newly created. Or else just have it return EXISTS if the entry already exists, and adjust your client accordingly.